# Payment method displaying twice in front end

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, module

I'm trying to swap from an old version of Realex payments module developed by SF9 to a new one built by Yoma. Both of these modules use the same resource name and the same table names so to get the new plugin to install I've removed the resource from core_resources and dropped the tables.

I've managed to do some test payments successfully however there seems to be one small issue with the module, the payment option displays twice in the checkout. this seems limited to just this modules payment options as the default magento options I've tested only display once.

The html output for these is also identical so it seems like a accidental dump of the same item twice. so while i could hide one with JS or CSS I'm trying to avoid this option for now.

[image]

Unfortunately there is seems to be no support for this module from what I can find, so I'm left trying to debug it by myself.

I've gone through the code and tried to debug the issue myself however I'm working blind when it comes to adding a new payment option. **What would be a good string to search for, or a config option I need to look for that would be prudent to look for to find a duplicated payment option?**

**Edit:**

I have now installed a fresh Magento installation and just the module with the same settings and it doesn't display twice.

So I turned off every non standard Magento module and set the theme to default on my staging site, but my staging site is still showing the payment option twice. So i assume this must be something to do with the database.

Comment: I assume that in the process of migration, you have removed the complete folder of the module developed by previous developers, right ?

Comment: I have not, this new module by a different developer has a different namespace so I've not just installed one over the top of the other, I have however only set the active state in the old module config file to false and not gone file by file deleting all traces of the extension.

Comment: Payment methods come from the module's config files and Models. You are gonna have to delete files from old module. Disabling old module should've done that, but just in case, I'd suggest removing files too.

Comment: I tried deleting every tile form the old and new module and reinstalling the new module but it still shows up twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was due to an old reference in the database. In the core_config_data table there was a row with the following in the path column: payment/realex/model

In the same row, in the value column the following will be entered: realex/redirect

The value needed changing to to NULL. Seems this is an old reference to the Studio Forty9 plugin.